# How to Monitor Sockets activity in a computer?

Tags: sockets, monitoring

I want to write a program **from scratch** to see the sockets activity, what they send, what they receive, etc. I **don't want to use a Library** because it's more for academic purposes than anything else.

Where should I start?

Just to be clear: my program won't be connecting to anything or creating any socket, it just wants to listen to the activity in a computer.

Any thoughts (in any OS) about where to start will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [libpcap/WinPcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap).

Comment: This would be my suggestion to.

Note that under Windows wireless connections are not easily captured, see Q-16 from http://www.winpcap.org/misc/faq.htm, and http://www.cacetech.com/products/airpcap.html

Comment: More than using a Library I want to know if someone has the knowledge of the low-level steps to build something like this.

Answer (score 2):

You are out of luck as far as portability goes.

Although the application APIs are the same or similar for UNIX and Windows, and, both implementations are historically based on the same Berkeley Sockets BSD code, the operating system architecture and hence the ways you access low level OS functions such as network IO are completely different.

Linux has a number of 'network sniffing' tools(tcpdump, ethereal etc.) easily available. Not so sure about windows, MS provides a Network Monitor and there are some tools available -- Google 'Sysinternals TDImon' for the MS tools.